# Unable to initialize OpenGL renderer library

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I am trying to open a virtual android device using genymotion. The problem is that it will not able to start Genymotion virtual device.Theirs an error display that it was unable to initialize OpenGL renderer library. I already check the OpenGL support and its was version 3.0. What is the problem now?

> Unable to initialize OpenGL renderer library.

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your log files ? https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-logs

Comment: I am new to this one.I'll just click play in Genymotion to test the device that I added.I didn't go to eclipse to run an application

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that ended up costing me quite some time.

In my case, I was using an older Intel graphics card driver that prevented me from using Genymotion after upgrading to Windows 8.1.

I tried multiple StackOverflow posts that did not lead me anywhere .Ultimately after I uninstalled my older driver and installed the newest version from

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx

the problem no longer occurred.

Though this problem may be fairly specific, I shall leave this here in hopes that it might help others who run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to update your graphics card driver, if your graphics card is from intel(included)
you can visit this site for updating

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx

note: Requires Java (if java confirm to update, try to update first)

then after updating your graphics card driver, try to reinstall your genymotion application, but don't remove the templates(your virtual device that was created before) then after installing try again

my problem is solved bby this technique, hope you problem solved too :)

EDIT:

This problem because your machine didn't support OpenGL 2, you can check the OpenGL version using this software

http://ononesoft.cachefly.net/support/DoctorGL.exe.zip

[image: screen capture of DoctorGL]

You can see the marked section(inside red line) that's says my openGL was updated to 2.x version

Comment: I too have similar problem ,trying to solved it .I almost tried everything whatever is given as a solution but nothing is working .It is show video card open gl error. Like failed to initialize backend egl.Here is my video card details-Video Card Vendor:    Intel
Renderer:             Intel 965/963 Graphics Media Accelerator
OpenGL Version:       1.5.0 - Build 7.14.10.1504
GLU Version:          1.2.2.0 Microsoft Corporation

Current pixel format: 6

Pixel Formats supported by this video card

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i solved this in my intel core i3 :

Goto control panle > System and Security > Windows Update > Check for updates

Now in the selected update list make sure to check the options Intel Corporation - Graphics AdapterWDDM1.1,Graphics Adapter WDDM1.2, Graphics Adapter WDDM1.3 -Intel(R)HD Graphics and Intel - Other hardware -Intel(R) Management Engine Interface.

After updating genymotion works as expected.
You can manually download driver for intel from https://downloadcenter.intel.com/

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue after updating the video driver unlike others over here who had to update the video driver to resolve this. I had to update Java and the Android APK to resolve this error.