# Android with genymotion

Tags: android, ubuntu, genymotion

I have installed both Virtual Box and genymotion and virtual device.

When I start virtual device Nexus-S it gives me this error:

Unable to start Genymotion virtual device. 
Unable to initialize OpenGl renderer library. 
Check if the video card support OpenGL 2.0
In Ubuntu
how can I make it run now?
Please Help

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684433/unable-to-initilize-opengl-renderer-library

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to tell you that geny motion cant run without graphic memory and opengl.
I think you doesn't have graphic card or opengl so it will not work till you doesn't  have these things 
:)

Comment: I have OPENGL installed and all graphic card things .But it is not recognised by ubuntu and also genymotion.So,What can i do now?

Comment: Try to update your driver See here https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-opengl-crash

Answer (score 0):

try to download the lower android version loke sony xperia s
or any other mobile of android 2.3 version
It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Download genymotion from website  [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) 
After that, you can install type this below command.

```
cd ~/Downloads/   

chmod +x genymotion-2.1.0_x64.bin

./genymotion-2.1.0_x64.bin
```

PS: This is guide for Ubuntu Users.